# Jenkins integration with Artifactory

Tags: java, jenkins, artifactory

I am trying to integrate Jenkins with Artifactory to deploy maven builds to artifactory repositories.
When I am taking the build in Jenkins, getting the following error in console output.

“ERROR: Processing failed due to a bug in the code. Please report this to jenkinsci-users@googlegroups.com
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching Artifactory server was found in General Configuration. Please update your job configuration” .

I have configured one Artifactory Server with default username and password. I left 'Use Different Resolver Credentials' box as unchecked. I did the Test Connection as well and got the message "Found Artifactory 2.6.7".But I could not do the configuration changes mentioned under "Configuring Maven 2 and Maven 3 Builds" since there is no option to do the post build step in my screen.

I am using Jenkins version 1.509, Artifactory pro version 2.6.7 and Jenkin-artifactory plugin  version 2.2.1.
Is my issue because of the version incompatibilities between these ?If yes, can anyone suggest me the compatible version of them for the CI integration ? My project team suggests to use Jenkins 1.509.So it will be great if some one can tell me the suitable versions of both Artifactory product and Jenkin-artifactory plugin matching to Jenkins version 1.509 
Also please advise me that what all changes are required under Jenkins > ['MyJobs'] > configuration

Answer (score 0):

The compatible versions are listed in [the documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin). Did you set up the Artifactory Server in the General Configuration as the error message suggests?

Comment: Hi JBaruch,

Yes.I have configured one Artifactory Server with default username and password. I left 'Use Different Resolver Credentials' box as unchecked. I did the Test Connection as well. I have got the message "Found Artifactory 2.6.7".

But I could not do the configuration changes mentioned under "Configuring Maven 2 and Maven 3 Builds" since there is no option to do the post build step in my screen.

Comment: Alos please advise me that what all changes are required under     Jenkins > ['MyJobs'] > configuration.

Comment: Please add this info to the question so I could delete my answer (which is not an answer :D)